# UITextView bullet point handling

Tags: ios, uitextview

TL;DR: Is there either a built-in way of using bullets in a UITextView, or is there a way using TextKit to do this, or are there individual workarounds to the four issues I have described below with the method I'm already using? Please read on for a full description of the method I have tried and the issues therein.

I've been experimenting with adding bullet point handling to a UITextView subclass. It is important this this should be editable, not just for displaying the text.

For adding a bullet, I get the start position of the paragraph the cursor is currently within, and insert the bullet character in that position.

```
UITextPosition *startOfParaPosition = [self startOfCurrentParagraph];
NSInteger startOfParaOffset = [self offsetFromPosition:self.beginningOfDocument toPosition:startOfParaPosition];

NSMutableAttributedString *mAttributedString = [self.attributedText mutableCopy];
NSAttributedString *bullet = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"• "];
[mAttributedString insertAttributedString:bullet atIndex:startOfParaOffset];
[self setAttributedText:mAttributedString];
```

Then I get the whole range of the current paragraph.

```
NSRange range = [self rangeOfCurrentParagraph];
```

Finally, I get the existing style of the current paragraph, amend the indentation, and then reapply the paragraph style.

```
[self getParagraphStyleInString:self.attributedText range:range completion:^(NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle) {
    paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 10.0;
    paragraphStyle.headIndent = 20.0;

    NSMutableAttributedString *mAttributedText = [self.attributedText mutableCopy];
    [mAttributedText addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:range];

    [super setAttributedText:mAttributedText];

}];
```

Note that I call `[super setAttributedText:]` here because I have overloaded this function in `self` to add some other styling, which I do not want to be applied at this time.

There are a number of problems with this approach.

1. Because the bullet glyph is added as a character within the text (rather than separate from it), it is possible for the user to select the bullet, and also to move the cursor before it. This means the user can delete the bullet glyph without the indentation changing, and can also insert characters before the bullet. This is not normal bullet point behaviour.
2. Although the bullet appears straight away, the indentation does not apply until something is typed into the UITextView.
3. Pressing Return within (or at the end of) a bulleted item continues the paragraph formatting (i.e. it is still indented correctly), but it obviously doesn't add another bullet to the text.
4. Backspacing to delete a bullet point and then continuing, so that the bulleted line moves up to the end of the previous line, causes the paragraph above to inherit the indented paragraph style of the bulleted item, not the other way round.

In short, using NSParagraphStyle and string-based bullet points does not seem to be a good solution for implementing bulleted lists in UITextView. I am aware that I could use a UIWebView with a contenteditable div, and this is indeed what I have been doing. However, I don't like having to use method swizzling to be able to modify the toolbars on a UIWebView keyboard, so would much rather use a UITextView. I also do not want to be using HTML as the format.

So, my question again: is there either a built-in way of using bullets in a UITextView, or is there a way using TextKit to do this, or are there individual workarounds to the four issues I wrote above with the method I'm already using?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you can't add a bullet character as a subview to UITextView at a needed position?

Comment: Because then the bullet wouldn't flow with the text. Adding new content above the bulleted paragraph which pushed it further down the view would leave the bullet subview(s) where they were when originally placed.

Comment: @mashers have you ever found a solution to your question? I'm also trying to replicate that behaviour.

Comment: @jbouaziz No, I didn't find a solution, and this project never got off the ground anyway is it was abandoned. Sorry I couldn't help.